# Run forEach in order of value inside of loop

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, ecmascript-6, foreach

I have a `forEach` loop that calls a function for each element in the loop. One of the elements is an element called `index` that has values as such:

```
"fields": [
                {
                    "label": "ID",
                    "index": 0.0
                },
                {
                    "label": "field 1",
                    "index": 1.0
                },
                {
                    "label": "field 2",
                    "index": 2.0
                },
                {
                    "label": "field 3",
                    "index": 2.7
                }
]
```

My Code:

```
const func2 = (result) => {
  result.data.fields.forEach((d) => {
    otherFunc(d.label);
  });
});

const otherFunc = (d) => //do something
```

As of now `otherFunc` is being called in any order. Can it be called based on the `index` field in `result from low to high. That is call in the order of` ID, field 1, field 2, field 3` instead of a random order.

Comment: it looks like sorted. so data.fields.forEach((d) is called in order?

Comment: The items will be enumerated in order.  If they're not being processed in order, then the structure does not look like what you have above.  If you want them sorted, then you need to sort it.

Comment: @cmgchess `otherFunc` is not called in order. The order I mentioned above is from `result`

Comment: @TimRoberts How do I sort it?

Comment: @nb_nb_nb is your `otherFunc` an async function? Can you share what it does

Comment: @Rajesh, it add those records to another db

Comment: Which seems like an async function. Try using async await

Comment: try using async await with a for loop instead of for each

Answer (score 3):

You can sort the fields array based on the *index* value before iterating over it:

```
....
result.data.fields
 .sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index) //sort the fields array based on the index
 .forEach((d) => {
   otherFunc(d.label);
 });
....
```

Answer (score 2):

You first need to sort your array :

try this :

```
 const func2 = (result) => {
    result.data.fields
  .sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index) // sort by index in ascending order
   .forEach((d) => {
    otherFunc(d.label);
  });
 };

 const otherFunc = (d) => {
   // do something
  };
```